# How to send receipt for previous event sign ups?

Tags: civievent, wordpress, 4.5.6

I set up an event registration form without enabling confirmation emails. We just got a request for a receipt from a registrant. I can't find a way to send a confirmation/receipt email to them a day after they signed up. Or a way for the user to access a receipt on our site. (I have since changed our sign up form to include the auto confirmation email.)

CiviCRM 4.5.6, WordPress 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to test the following:

1. Navigate to Administer Communications > Message Templates, select System Messages, then beside Events - Receipt only. Leave this window open and open another to Administer Communications > Message Templates, and click New template. Copy the subject, html body and text body from system receipt message into you new user one, give it a name and save it.
2. Navigate to Find Participants, select a registration of your own user for testing (you may need to create one first), then for action select Send email to participants. On the next page, select your new template and send the message. If the receipt looks good in your inbox, repeat this step but sending to unreceipted participant.

Comment: For now what I did was screen capture the contribution screen for the payment, and email a jpeg to the person.

Comment: I tried that, but looks like this idea doesn't work. The message is sent without processing the Tokens. I thought the problem was that the Tokens there are formated to serial processing, with if/elses, etc, and so I think I could make a new message with some basic event Tokens, not the default receipt, but I found that event tokens are not available from the Tokens panel. Are they not available at all to this kind of email messaging?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback diegov, since I suggeated trying something I hadn't tested. Can you confirm you did the send on results of Find Participants?

Comment: This did not work for me.  All I get is the an e-mail with the code.